# Shell script to Upload files from AWS EC2 to S3

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jmeter

I am executing jmeter on AWS EC2, result of which is returned in the form csv file.

I need to upload this csv file to AWS S3 bucket.

Since I am creating number of EC2 instances dynamically and executing jmeter on those instances, it's better to automate this process .

So for this I want to write shell script (as a user data) to execute jmeter and upload result CSV file to S3 bucket from each EC2 instance.

How i can write script for this ?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using command line s3 clients.

[S3 command line tools](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

Also go through some of these sites :

[Shell Script To Transfer Files From Amazon S3 Bucket.](http://arunsasidhar.blogspot.in/2011/07/shell-script-to-transfer-files-from.html)

[aws command line tools](http://timkay.com/aws/)

[python script to upload file to s3](https://code.google.com/p/s3afe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for managing objects on AWS S3 using shell scripts.

[Universal Docs Manager](https://github.com/aishwarydhare/universal-docs-manager) is Pure shell script based objects manager which currently supports Local Disk, MySQL and AWS S3